# How to format Razor code containing VB code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I want to format a block of code from a `.vbhtml` file. That is VB.NET code embedded in a Razor code file. So the parser/formatter needs to understand Razor syntax and VB.NET syntax. Could such a language format be implemented on SO, or what would be the best substitute?

As an example, the first block of code in this answer needs to be formatted as Razor VB.NET code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290579/78162

Ideally the code would look like this:
[image]

Comment: See linked faq, under "Language Codes"

Comment: There were so many questions and answers relating to code formatting, I apparently couldn't find the one that listed the available languages. Maybe I need some help in how I perform my searches. Nevertheless I think this question is still appropriate as a feature request for Razor syntax support. I will update the question to focus on that aspect.

Comment: Does Google Prettify support Razor?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN first of all I look in the [meta-tag:faq] tag plus relevant tag, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting+faq then narrow the search down with key words if needed. Usually works. As for unsupported languages, that's a request for Google, not Stack Exchange.